# How do I make a web page with the lists of tweets of celebrities with Twitter API?

Tags: api, twitter

I'm trying to make a web page with multiple lists of tweets of celebrities. 
How do I get multiple tweets of various people with Twitter API?
What I'm thinking of is just like the link below:
https://togetter.com/li/1421486

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "user_mentions"

example

```
      "user_mentions": [
        {
          "name": "John Doe",
          "id_str": "12345678",
          "id": 12345678,
          "indices": [
            0,
            11
          ],
```